# Why does Github list the Ubuntu computer's name as author instead of my Github account name when I push from command line?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, git, github

When I `git push` from a terminal on my Ubuntu box, which has a computer name of `Bot`, it asks for Github credentials, and I provide them.  The username I provide is my own, not `Bot`.  Yet when I go to github.com I see that the credit for authoring the code I pushed has gone to `Bot` instead of me.  How do I get it to attribute the changes to my Github username?  Can I retroactively tell Github that all those Bot changes were actually pushed by me?

Comment: Does `git config --get user.name` and `git config --get user.email` give you what you're expecting?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git

Comment: Thanks!  Think there's anyway to have Github change authorship of those past commits to my username?  Can I use git to change the commits themselves locally?

Comment: Read this: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info

Comment: The **WHY** part is not answered and it also happens on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in comments:

use:

```
git config --get user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "you@here.com"
```

To set your configurations so your future commits will be taken cocertly.

Comment: I've transcribed the response, only to make the question more indexable, and help other users that need it.